# Correct workflow? - Distributable environment including jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pipenv

I am developing applications that use Jupyter notebook and ipywidgets for a GUI frontend to a backend codebase. I have run into issues distributing/installing packages in the normal way, such as:

- unexpected differences between required library versions (e.g. pandas)
- requirements.txt forcing an update to more recent version of a library when the user maintains and uses their own codebase on an older version of that library.

I think pipenv might be able to solve this problem, but I want to check I have a correct usage before going too far down this path.

Requirements:

- the user needs to be able to restart Jupyter Notebook in the same env multiple times, running the program from scratch, until a new version is available.
- Users are all on Mac.
- Any installation should not alter `site-packages` etc, have no effect on the python setup any user currently has.

---

**Workflow concept**

Development:

1. Develop within a pipenv environment (I use Pycharm so this is relatively straightforward).
2. Include `jupyter` in Pipfile `[requires]`, even though `jupyter` is not imported anywhere in my source.
3. Use `pipenv install new_package` as and when new packages are required by my codebase, and maintain the Pipfile (respecting --dev for testing packages etc).

User installation

1. Produce a zip file containing source code, setup.py etc plus Pipfile and Pipfile.lock.
2. User extracts the zip file to a known location on their machine.
3. In terminal, navigate to the unzipped folder location, and run `pipenv install`.

Use:

1. In terminal, navigate to the folder location, and run `pipenv shell`
2. Run `pipenv run jupyter notebook` to reload the env and notebook.
3. When finished, close out of notebook and run `exit` to close the env.

Uninstall env and upgrade to newer version

1. In terminal, navigate to the folder location, and run `pipenv --rm`.
2. Download new source zip and follow steps above.

---

If I've understood, this should ensure anyone can use the distribution in a tightly controlled environment, without making any alterations to their existing python install? Have I overcomplicated things?